# How can I add require.js to my AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have controllers in my AngularJS application that are currently coded like this:

```
app.controller('appController',
    [
        '$state',
        '$timeout',
        'enumService',
        'userService',
        'utilityService',
        appController
    ]);

function appController(
    $scope,
    $state,
    $timeout,
    enumService,
    userService,
    utilityService
) {

    ...

}
```

**What I would like to start doing is to use require.js to handle lazy-loading of the controllers.** I learned that I should use something like this:

```
require(["app"], function (app) {
     app.controller('appController', function appController(
         $scope,
         $state,
         $timeout,
         enumService,
         userService,
         utilityService
     ) {

         ...

     });
});
```

Can someone please explain to me how the app.controller can get a reference to the services? Do I need to do anything else on the require.js side? Am I on the right track with the way I am coding the appController?

Comment: maybe have a look at this: https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed

Comment: I am trying for such an integration plus lazy loading (using [this](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy)), [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy). Angular and Require have quite an impedance mismatch, but you may (or may not) get some ideas.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

***tl;dr; the final solution is in the last section or just look at [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6CLDsz?p=preview)***

---

## Lazy Loading with `$injector`

The [**angular-requirejs-seed**](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed) project illustrates how you can easily implement lazy loading by setting up a lazy function like this:

```
define([], function() {
    return ['$scope', '$http', 'myInjectable', function($scope, $http, myInjectable) {
        $scope.welcomeMessage = 'hey this is myctrl2.js!';

        // because this has happened async, we've missed the digest cycle
        $scope.$apply();
    }];
});
```

... and then instantiating the controller like this:

```
.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', '$injector', function($scope, $injector) {
    require(['controllers/myctrl2'], function(myctrl2) {
        $injector.invoke(myctrl2, this, {'$scope': $scope});
    });
...
```

Note that the lazily-loaded *function* is not a controller. It's just a function invoked with the `$injector` which gives it access to the actual controller's `$scope` and `this`, and allows it to access any of the *injectables* loaded in your app.

You can apply this same technique to a **service**, **factory**, or **directive**.

---

## Lazy-loading Caveats

**In most cases, lazy-loading is probably self-defeating**. If your goal is to give your users a snappy website, then lazily loading every controller is a bad idea. Once an HTTP connection is established, most internet connections allow a lot of data to flow over the wire in a short period of time. Latency, however can be the real killer. That's why most sites these days use concatenation and minification to package their javascript and decrease the number of network requests, rather than relying on lazy-loading which increases the number of requests.

Consider the architecture of your app. How many re-usable directives will you create? How much code will be shared among various pieces of the app, unsuited for lazy-loading? For many apps, **much of the code will be comprised of common components, making lazy-loading pointless**.

**Lazy loading makes sense in an app with very distinct and separate pieces**. Pieces that are so distinct and separate they can be thought of as separate apps. However, even in this case you might consider actually creating separate apps rather than combining them.

> ---
>
> #### BTW, require.js is still useful even if you're not Lazy-loading
>
> Even if you're not lazy-loading, **require.js is extremely useful for
>   dependency management**. Used in conjunction with the require.js
>   optimizer it's an elegant way to keep track of dependencies and
>   compress+minify your app.
>
> You can also use require.js to load dependencies for running Jasmine
>   unit tests which helps keep your components modular, and speeds up
>   your tests by just loading the dependencies that you need. For unit
>   testing, I create a separate **main-test.js** file which calls
>   `require.config(...)` to load app dependencies as well as
>   testing-specific dependencies.
>
> ---

---

## Lazy-loading Architecture

Lazy-loading with angular is rather complicated because angular isn't designed to support lazy-loading. In this section I will attempt to take you on an exploration on how one might coerce angular to support lazy-loading. This isn't a full-blown solution, but I hope to present concepts which are important to understand when building such a application.

Let's begin at the router, as opposed to the *angular-requirejs-seed* I presented in the first section, it actually makes a lot more sense for lazy-loading to live in your application's *router*. Using **ui-router**, we can implement lazy-loading this way:

```
...
app.$controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
var lazyPartialDeferred;

$stateProvider
  ...
  .state('lazy', {
    url: "/lazy",
    templateProvider: function() { return lazyPartialDeferred.promise; },
    controller: 'lazyCtrl',
    resolve: {
      load: function($q, $templateCache) {
        var lazyCtrlDeferred = $q.defer();
        lazyPartialDeferred = $q.defer();
        require(['lazy'], function (lazy) {
          lazyCtrlDeferred.resolve();
          lazyPartialDeferred.resolve($templateCache.get('lazy.html'));
        });
        return lazyCtrlDeferred.promise;
      }
    }
  });
...
```

What we are doing here is *deferring* instantiation of both the partial (lazy.html) and the controller (lazyCtrl) until after our requirejs module (lazy.js) is loaded. Also, note that **we load our view partial, *lazy.html* directly from the $templateCache**. That is, when we loaded lazy.js, the partial itself was included with lazy.js. In theory, we could have just loaded lazy.html separately from lazy.js but for best performance we should compile partials into our js files.

Let's take a look at **lazy.js**:

```
define(['angular', 'lazy-partials'], function (angular) {
  var app = angular.module('app');

  var lazyCtrl =  ['$scope', '$compile', '$templateCache', function ($scope, $compile, $templateCache) {
    $scope.data = 'my data';
  }];

  app.$controllerProvider.register('lazyCtrl', lazyCtrl);
});
```

Keep in mind, the above code represents the *uncompiled* lazy.js. In production, lazy-partials.js (referenced in the first line above) will actually be compiled into the same file.

Now let's take a look at **lazy-partials.js**:

```
// Imagine that this file was actually compiled with something like grunt-html2js
// So, what you actually started with was a bunch of .html files which were compiled into this one .js file...
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
  var $injector = angular.element(document).injector(),
      $templateCache = $injector.get('$templateCache');

  $templateCache.put('lazy.html', '<p>This is lazy content! and <strong>{{data}}</strong> <a href="#">go back</a></p>');
});
```

Once again, the above code isn't exactly what such a file would really look like. *lazy-partials.js* would actually be generated automatically from your html files using a build tool plugin like grunt-html2js.

Now, you could, in theory build your entire app using the approach presented thus far. However, it's a little... janky. What we would much rather do in our lazy.js is instantiate a new module, like `appLazy = angular.module('app.lazy')` and then instantiate our controller, directives, services, etc like `appLazy.directive(...)`.

However, the reason we can't do this is because all of that stuff is initialized (and made available to our app) in the `angular.bootstrap` method which has already been called by the time *lazy.js* is loaded. And we can't just call `angular.bootstrap(...)` again.

> ---
>
> #### BTW, internally angular is doing this to bootstrap modules:
>
> ```
>       var injector = createInjector(modules, config.strictDi);
> ```
>
> `createInjector` is an internal function to angular that loops through
>   all of the modules and registers all of their various building blocks.
>
> In **lazy.js**, we called `$controllerProvider.register(..)` to
>   lazily register our controller. `createInjector` also triggers a
>   call to the same function when the app is bootstrapped. Here is a list
>   of various angular building blocks and the way in which they are
>   registered by angular:
>
> ```
> provider: $provide.provider
> factory: $provide.factory
> service: $provide.service
> value: $provide.value
> constant: $provide.constant.unshift
> animation: $animateProvider.register
> filter: $filterProvider.register
> controller: $controllerProvider.register
> directive: $compileProvider.directive
> ```
>
> ---

So, is there a way to lazily instantiate modules? Yes, **[you can register a module and it's sub-modules by iterating through various nested properties of the module object (`requires` and `_invokeQueue`)](http://blog.getelementsbyidea.com/load-a-module-on-demand-with-angularjs/)**, an operation which has been simplified in a lib called **[ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/blob/master/src/ocLazyLoad.js)**.

**Most of the code presented in this section is available in *[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mN1tRW?p=preview)***.

(Sources of inspiration not mentioned above: [Couch Potato](https://github.com/stu-salsbury/angular-couch-potato/blob/master/src/couchPotato.js), [AngularAMD](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD))

---

## The Complete Lazy-loading Solution:

#### [ `ocLazyLoad`+`ui-router`+`requirejs` ] - [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OGvi01?p=preview)

Because **ui-router** allows us to defer loading of the template and the controller, we can use it in conjunction with **ocLazyLoad** to load modules on-the-fly between route changes. This example builds off of the principles of the previous section, but by utilizing **ocLazyLoad** we have a solution that allows our lazily-loaded modules to be structured in the same way as the non-lazy-loaded ones.

The key piece here is our `app.config(..)` block:

```
  app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    var lazyDeferred;

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
      loadedModules: ['app'],
      asyncLoader: require
    });

    $stateProvider
      ...
      .state('lazy', {
        url: "/lazy",
        templateProvider: function() { return lazyDeferred.promise; },
        controller: 'lazyCtrl',
        resolve: {
          load: function($templateCache, $ocLazyLoad, $q) {
            lazyDeferred = $q.defer();
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              name: 'app.lazy', 
              files: ['lazy']
            }).then(function() {
              lazyDeferred.resolve($templateCache.get('lazy.html'));
            });
          }
        }
      });
    ...
```

**lazy.js** now looks like this:

```
define(['angular', 'lazy-partials'], function (angular) {
  var appLazy = angular.module('app.lazy', ['app.lazy.partials']);

  appLazy.controller('lazyCtrl', function ($scope, $compile, $templateCache) {
    $scope.data = 'my data';
  });
});
```

Notice that there's no longer anything special about this file in terms of lazy-loading. You could just as easily load this file in a non-lazy fashion and it wouldn't know the difference. The same principle applies to **lazy-partials.js**:

```
// Imagine that this file was actually compiled with something like grunt-html2js
// So, what you actually started with was a bunch of .html files which were compiled into this one .js file...
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
  angular.module('app.lazy.partials', [])
    .run(function($templateCache) {
      $templateCache.put('lazy.html', '<p>This is lazy content! and <strong>{{data}}</strong> <a href="#">go back</a></p>');
    });
});
```

---

### >>> **[check out the fully-functioning plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OGvi01?p=preview)** <<<

---

#### Deployment

When it comes to deployment, the final piece to this puzzle is to use the requirejs optimizer to concatenate and minimize our js files. Ideally, we want the optimizer to skip concatenation of dependencies that are already included in the main app (ie: common files). To accomplish this, [see this repo](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim) and it's accompanying [build.js file](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim/blob/master/tools/build.js).

---

#### An even more elegant solution

We can improve on the previous plunk by adding a ui-router decorator for **[a very elegant solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/6CLDsz?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was not quite the answer I expected but I am very interested in using this as a possible alternative. I would review your answer more and get back to you.

Comment: I played with the your plunk a bit and came up with this... http://plnkr.co/edit/iNoco8?p=preview This uses text and css plugin of the require. I am fairly new to angular but know good amount of requireJS (so please correct if I have made any mistake). Above plunk will allow us to merge all three js, html and css in same file using r.js easily.

Comment: I was wondering if we can remove ocLazyLoad somehow with some more bits in our files, that will be great..

Comment: This is great, app.js looks much cleaner now. I will take this, but this is not what I was talking about, I wanted to remove ocLazyLoad completely from the project and get the code from it which registers the controllers since we are using requireJS anyway for downloadin the dependencies. But No worries, I will take this, 17KB (lesser if minified) will not hurt much...

Comment: ocLazyLoad does include some file-loading features that you won't need if you're using requirejs. It's main purpose however (and the way it's used here), is to bootstrap modules at run-time. So if you'd like to slim it down, you'd have to fork ocLazyLoad and just remove the file-loading parts that you don't need.